# pdfgrep doesn't work with arabic langauge strings

Tags: linux, grep, terminal, pdf, pdfgrep

I want to use pdf grep and it works when I want to search by an Arabic text or string. it shows nothing. however, it works properly when I search by an English string. Does anyone have a solution or even an alternative? Thank you
this is the code I used btw

```
pdfgrep -in 'احمد' name.pdf
```

Comment: Are you using the same document in your tests for English and Arabic text? Is the document searchable? I ask this because I did a quick test with a sample pdf and pdfgrep seems to be able to find Arabic characters (specifically, poppler should recognize unicode characters)

Answer (score 0):

I won't lie, I don't know enough about the Arabic language and it's implementation in UTF to make an educated guess as to what may be causing this. However, you might want to check [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402363/how-do-i-grep-for-arabic-characters-with-diacritical-marks) out. Hope it helps

(I would have put this in a comment, but I'm a new contributor so I can't yet)